# Getting values from NSValue that was created using sizeWithAttributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsvalue

I have an NSValue that I am returning from an NSDictionary. The NSValue was created using **sizeWithAttributes**.
I would like to know how to get the NSValue back into a value where I can use it to create the label size.

I get the size of the label calculated from this

```
betweensLabelSize = [betweensString sizeWithAttributes: @{
                      NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.5f]
                }];
```

I put this into the NSDictionary as a NSValue and retrieve like so

```
NSValue *tempSize = [currAxisDictionary objectForKey:@"betweensLabelSize"];
```

which returns this value

```
NSSize: {64.278503, 86.4925}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, you presumably created the `NSValue` using `+[NSValue valueWithCGSize:]`. `-sizeWithAttributes:` didn't create the `NSValue`; it returned a `CGSize` which you wrapped in an `NSValue`.

Anyway, you can get the `CGSize` out of the `NSValue` object by calling `-CGSizeValue` on it:

```
CGSize size = [tempSize CGSizeValue];
```

Comment: okay thanks for the reply, Im looking into it now but not 100% sure how to use CGSizeValue

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how the `CGSizeValue` method would be used to get a `CGSize` out of the `NSValue` object pointed to by `tempSize`.

Comment: That worked thanks. I have never used CGSizeValue before

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for accessing the size value:-

```
NSValue *val=[mut objectForKey:@"betweensLabelSize"];
CGSize sz=val.CGSizeValue;
```

Comment: Please mention the reason for downvote. So that will correct the answer.

Comment: Sorry but everything in your answer is incorrect. The OP's line to get the `NSValue` `tempSize` from the dictionary is just fine. It does *not* return a `CGSize`, it returns an `NSValue`. Your suggested solution will crash. The OP's goal is to extract the `CGSize` value from the `NSValue`. See the docs for `NSValue` for a simple way to do this.

Comment: `NSValue` does not have a property named `sizeValue`. Perhaps you meant to use the `CGSizeValue` method.

Comment: Right that only i meant